# How use a conditional statement in a Flask app?

Tags: python, html, flask

What I am trying to do is to trigger the function get_lyrics() when the Submit button is clicked. That action might run successfully which then triggers another action, or it might fail showing instead 'API calls reached. Try again later.'

However, as soon as I load the page, the text 'API calls reached. Try again later.' is already there whereas it should only appear when the function that is triggered fails.

This is my app.py:

```
import os
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from src.get_lyrics import get_lyrics

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def web_page():
    return render_template('simple.html')


@app.route('/artist', methods=['POST'])
def insert_text():
    if request.method=='POST':
        artist_name = request.form.get("artist")
        number_songs = request.form.get("number")

        try:
            titles, lyrics, no_of_songs = get_lyrics(artist = artist_name,
                                                     max_no_songs = number_songs,
                                                     path_to_txt="C:/Users/test_new.txt")
            train = True

        except:
            train = False
            titles= None
            no_of_songs = None

    return render_template('simple.html', titles=titles, no_songs=no_of_songs, train=train)
```

and this is the html bit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link href="static/simple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"</link>

<html>

<div class="image"></div>

    <body>
        <div class="gray-block-1">
            <div class="block-1">
                <h2>Instructions</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="block-2">
                <form action = "./artist" method = "POST">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Artist name" name="artist" />
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Number of songs" name="number" />
                  <div class="submit-button">
                    <button type = "submit"> Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="gray-block-2">

            {% if train %}
                {% for title in titles %}
                <p>{{title}}</p
                {% endfor %}

                    <form action = "./train" method = "POST">
                        <input type = "text" placeholder="Number of lines" name = "lines" />
                        <div class="submit-button-2">
                            <button type = "predict"> Predict</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    {% else %}
                        API calls reached. Try again later.
                {% endif %}
        </div>

      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to implement rate limiting. This is usually done through the webserver rather than the application.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `simple.html` is loaded for the first time with a `GET` request, the variable `train` is not defined. `if train` will therefore return `False` and the text in the `else` statement will be shown: *“API calls reached. Try again later.”*

You could set another variable in the backend.

```
@app.route('/artist', methods=['POST'])
def insert_text():
    …
    return render_template('simple.html', is_post=True, …)
```

And update the front end accordingly.

```
<div class="gray-block-2">
    {% if is_post %}
        {% if train %}
            …
        {% else %}
            API calls reached. Try again later.
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

There is probably a better way. I'm just trying to point you in the right direction.